# glDrawArrays() behaving weirdly on Mac OS X

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am practicing the usage of VBOs in OpenGL with Java and LWJGL (using this tutorial, and basically copying it's code: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html) and right now something really weird is happening.

I have a window set up and this is my render() function, called inside the main loop:

```
public void render() {

    FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(3 * 3);

    buffer.put(-1);
    buffer.put(-1);
    buffer.put(0);

    buffer.put(0);
    buffer.put(1);
    buffer.put(0);

    buffer.put(1);
    buffer.put(-1);
    buffer.put(0);

    buffer.flip();

    int vbo = glGenBuffers();

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, 0);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

}
```

As you can see, it's very simple code which should draw a triangle. But what I get on a Mac OS X Mountain Lion laptop, running Intel HD 4000 graphics is this:
[image]

And what I get on Windows 7, running AMD HD 6850 graphics is this:
[image]

Why is that? I really see no reason for this to happen, both of the video cards support OpenGL 2.0, which is what I'm using, right?

Comment: Did you add natives in your project?

Comment: Yes I did. LWJGL's Window, Mouse and Keyboard classes are working fine.

Comment: Actually in OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion) you are using OpenGL 3.2. If you have a core profile context, and fail to bind a Vertex Array Object, then this is pretty much the kind of behaviour you can expect :)

Comment: I don't get it. Why is glGetString(GL_VERSION) returning 2.1 INTEL-8.12.47?

Comment: @Thiago You have to change the context manually. Not sure how to do it in Java but I'm sure it's somewhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I devoted a lot of time to solving this issue when I first started to use VAO objects. It was very frustrating to say the least.

I ultimately figured it out and I guess it comes down to a glitch in the compatibility profile that  requires you to have used glLinkProgram and glUseProgram on a shader prior to calling glGenVertexArrays, even though the program requirement should have been relaxed outside the Core profile...

The easiest solution is to simply replace:

`GL30.glGenVertexArrays` with `APPLEVertexArrayObject.glGenVertexArraysAPPLE`
`GL30.glBindVertexArray`with  `APPLEVertexArrayObject.glBindVertexArrayAPPLE`
`GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays` with `APPLEVertexArrayObject.glDeleteVertexArrayAPPLE`

You can also overcome the problem by compiling a shader and calling glUseProgram prior to using `GL30.glGenVertexArrays` ...