# JOGL glBufferData with glVertexAttribPointer not working

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I have a problem regarding glBufferData and glVertexAttribPointer. For some reason, they just don't work together. Here is the code:

```
    float[] triangleArray = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f    
    };

    IntBuffer vacantNameBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(2);
    gl.glGenBuffers(1, vacantNameBuffer);
    int bufferIndex = vacantNameBuffer.get();

    FloatBuffer triangleVertexBuffer = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(triangleArray);
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferIndex);
    IntBuffer paramBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(2);
    gl.glGetBufferParameteriv(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL2.GL_BUFFER_SIZE, paramBuffer);
    System.out.println(paramBuffer.get());
    int triangleBufferSize = triangleVertexBuffer.capacity() * Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT;
    gl.glBufferData(
            GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
            triangleBufferSize,
            triangleVertexBuffer, 
            GL2.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glGetBufferParameteriv(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL2.GL_BUFFER_SIZE, paramBuffer);
    System.out.println(paramBuffer.get());
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(
            0, 
            3, 
            GL2.GL_FLOAT, 
            false, 
            0, 
            0);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    gl.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

However, this works perfectly:

```
    float[] triangleArray = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f    
    };

    FloatBuffer triangleVertexBuffer = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(triangleArray);
    /*
    IntBuffer vacantNameBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(2);
    gl.glGenBuffers(1, vacantNameBuffer);
    int bufferIndex = vacantNameBuffer.get();
    gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferIndex);
    IntBuffer paramBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(2);
    gl.glGetBufferParameteriv(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL2.GL_BUFFER_SIZE, paramBuffer);
    System.out.println(paramBuffer.get());
    int triangleBufferSize = triangleVertexBuffer.capacity() * Buffers.SIZEOF_FLOAT;
    gl.glBufferData(
            GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
            triangleBufferSize,
            triangleVertexBuffer, 
            GL2.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.glGetBufferParameteriv(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL2.GL_BUFFER_SIZE, paramBuffer);
    System.out.println(paramBuffer.get());
    */
    gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    gl.glVertexAttribPointer(
            0, 
            3, 
            GL2.GL_FLOAT, 
            false, 
            0, 
            triangleVertexBuffer);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    gl.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

If someone would be so kind as to point out why my code doesn't work. I would be very grateful.

Comment: This example uses glBufferData and glVertexAttribPointer with JOGL successfully: http://jogamp.org/git/?p=jogl-demos.git;a=blob;f=src/demos/es2/RawGL2ES2demo.java;hb=HEAD If you don't follow my advices, it won't encourage me to investigate. Please look at my comment under your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828584/gldrawarrays-with-buffer-not-working-in-jogl

Comment: Rather use paramBuffer.get(int index) instead of paramBuffer.get(). If it (still) doesn't work, please try to comment the call of glGetBufferParameteriv in order to check whether the problem comes from that.

Comment: Oh thanks, I forgot to change th IntBuffer as well. I think I might have found something about the problem. I tried the demo on Windows 7 and Mac. The triangle shows on Windows OPENGL version 2.1.0 but not on Mac OPENGL version 4.1 (after I deleted the part with Shader Program because GLSL 130 is not supported). I don't know why, but I will try my code on windows to see whether it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, it was not with my code, but it's with the limitation on jogl that requires a gl shader program to be used. 
Found answer on this post: [glDrawArrays() behaving weirdly on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368914/gldrawarrays-behaving-weirdly-on-mac-os-x);